# SQL Tinder to prioritize order for users who already like you

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
profile
---
id  name
1   John
2   Jane
3   Jill
...

swipe
---
id  profile_1_id  profile_2_id  liked
1   2             1             true
2   3             1             false
...
```

If you've used Tinder before, you might recognize that it seems to fetch an initial card deck that consists of:

1. users who already like you that you can instantly match with, pushed to the top
2. other users
3. (out of scope for this question but it also sprinkles in some more attractive users)

If we extend the example to 100+ users, id=1 John was looking at the app, and we fetched with a limit of 20, it would guarantee Jane comes back (since Jane already likes John and John could match right away) + 19 others to fill the rest of John's deck to keep John swiping for more.

What is the SQL for "get people who like John first then fill the rest with random users"? Would this be a WHERE(case if else) or some other statement?

Comment: If you want to sort results you can use `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a query that should meet your need.

It works by using a conditional sorting with `CASE`. Users that liked John will are given higher priority, and will appear sorted by `id`. Other users are given a lower, random, priority ; this also means, for a given user, this part of list will not always be the same (which, I believe, fits your purpose). The number of output records is then controlled by a `LIMIT` clause.

I tested the query in [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=e87997a190718b619804f60859308c5e). You need to replace the question mark (`?`) in the `CASE` clause with the id of user for which you are generating a card (`1` for John in your sample data).

```
SELECT
    p.id, 
    p.name
FROM 
    profile p
    LEFT JOIN swipe s on s.profile_1_id = p.id
ORDER BY 
    CASE s.profile_2_id
        WHEN ? THEN 0
        ELSE FLOOR(random() * 10) + 1
    END,
    p.id
LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this but I think you're oversimplifying.  Do you want to exclude not liked people from the others?

```
  select * from profile p
    left outer join swipe s on (p.id=profile_1_id and s.profile_2_id  = 1 and liked = true)
    where 
     p.id<>1
    order by coalesce(profile_2_id , random()*-1000000) desc
    limit 20
```